# Managed Package Patch Modification Exception on package uploading

Tags: apex, lightning

Can anyone please help me with this.
I am getting this error while uploading a patch.
What is this "Feature dependency addition: LightningOnMobile".

[image]

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Sonal, that seems to be because you changed something related to LightningOnMobile custom object. Have you created a custom object or new fields?

Comment: Hi jeferson, i haven't created any custom object or field..i have checked the feature dependency but there is nothing like 'LightningOnMobile'..

Comment: Hi Sonal - I would create a support ticket then and post here any findings.

Comment: Hi Jeferson, Thank you so much for your effort. I appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, issue is resolved

Comment: Nice Sonal, did they told you what was the problem?

Comment: I am getting this too. But I noticed when i try to deploy to multiple orgs with push upgrades, the result is intermittent. First try I had 80% failures, then I repackaged and got about 50% failures... so ,must be a performance bug in sfdc side!?